# What is A intersect B

Tags: probability

Two dice are rolled

A - The first die shows an even number

B - The sum of the two die is 4

Now the question is for A it states only the first die so the second dice roll shouldn't factor in $(A=1/2)$. But A intersect B so would you need to take account the second roll $(A=1/16)$?

Comment: how does the second roll affect the first?

Comment: user207738, ask yourself some questions: when you roll the second die, does the first die change? (If you are playing the game of bocce ball with your dice, then you should include that in your problem statement.) Think about "independence".  For your follow up question, are you thinking about probability as the ratio of desired outcomes to possible outcomes? If there are 36 different pairs possible with two thrown die, how many of those pairs sum to 4? 1+3, 2+2, ...

Comment: @curiousgeorge I understand that the second roll would not factor in the first roll. But with the follow up question of A intersect B (Where B is the sum of the two dice is 4) would it then take account the second roll? Other wise how else would you compare 1 dice roll to 2?

Comment: Oops, I'm now asking myself a question about your original problem statement: what is "A"? I thought you were asking what's the probability that the sum of the two die is 4. It appears you may be asking a different question. Please provide more clarification in your original question.

Comment: @curiousgeorge sorry for the confusion, have updated question

Comment: OK, so if I understand, the desirable outcomes include pairs such that the first die is even.  That precludes 1+3 from being a desirable outcome. Yes, you need to consider the second die.  While there are 18 pairs with the first number even, only a very few of those (2+2) sum to 4.

Answer (score 1):

Second question:

A: First dice is even

B: Sum of both dices is 4

$P(A \cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B|A)$

$P(A)=\frac{1}{2}$ (As you said)

[image]

summe (german)=sum (english)

Look at the table. There are 18 outcomes for event A. 
How many of these outcomes have the sum of 4 ? Let this number be x.

$P(B|A)=\frac{x}{18}$

After you have investigated x, you can calculate $P(A \cap B)$